# visual lightbox overlay width isn't coming 100% in samsung mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out the problem but seems to be fail. I have put visual lightbox to one website which is working perfectly for desktop but for mobile with overlay bg width is not coming 100%.

here it is the website link: `http://bit.ly/1m9sbnC`

Please check in your Samsung/Android Mobile and help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

in the header ?